# D2L Per user Content Visibility

Tags: desire2learn

Can we unlock or unhide content for particular users or does that apply to all students in a D2L course?

Answer (score 0):

Hidden applies to all users in roles that do not have a "View Content that is Not Released" permission. The system does not manage hidden on a per user basis.

Not sure your specific application, but, because of this property of the system there are apps that apparently use a couple roles to control visibility of items and then swap between the roles dyanamically with the enrollment api. This is used for items like quizzes that are shown or hidden with role permissions. (Note: This does NOT work for restrictions aka release conditions if you are looking to "withdraw" visibility as you can't "unmeet" a Desire2Learn Content Restriction. But you could use this to progressively reveal content; it just might not be particularly graceful code).

Enrollments often have special meaning for systems, so you will want to check with your operations group to see if changing enrollments works with their plans/policies.